# Java Excel cutom filter does not show any rows

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, aspose

Below is what I am using to apply date filter between a specific range. But when I execute the code and open the excel file no rows are shown eventhough the filter is applied

```
public void dateAfterFilter(String sheetname, int totalRows, LocalDate value, LocalDate value1) throws Exception 
    {       
        worksheet = wb.getWorksheets().get(sheetname);
        worksheet.getAutoFilter().setRange("D1:D" + totalRows);
        worksheet.getAutoFilter().custom(0, FilterOperatorType.GREATER_THAN, value, true, FilterOperatorType.LESS_OR_EQUAL, value1);
        worksheet.getAutoFilter().refresh();
        saveWorkBook();
     }
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Have you tried using the "addDateFilter" method instead of the custom filter? I'm not sure how the custom filter is implemented and the API doesn't indicate whether the LESS_OR_EQUAL or GREATER_OR_EQUAL operators work on LocalDate objects.

Comment: java 11.0.8
Isnt the addDateFilter to get a specific date/month/year. I need the records with dates after this specific date

Comment: Could you please share your sample Excel file, we can check it. Also, you may post your issue with template file into Aspose forums (https://forum.aspose.com/).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.